# axios post data successfully but failed to assign location after response success instead res.json rendered to client as html page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

axios script.js file

```
const creatClient = async (client) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      withCredentials: true,
      url: '/[url]',
      data: client,
    }).then(location.assign('/[newUrl]'));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
submitbtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault;
  const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  const phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
  const createdATT = new Date(document.getElementById('date').value);
  const followUp = new Date(document.getElementById('date2').value);
  const images = document.getElementById('img').value;
  const insurance = document.getElementById('insurance').value;
  const client = { name, phone, insurance, images, createdATT, followUp };
  console.log(client);
  client ? creatClient(...client) : console.log('no object created');
});
```

controller file
the console log for req.body [Object: null prototype] {*** the object ***}

```
const multer = require('multer');
const Client = require('../models/clientModel');

const multerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'public/img');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const ext = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
    cb(null, `user-${Date.now()}.${ext}`);
  },
});
const multerFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype.startsWith('image')) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cd(console.log('select image'), false);
  }
};
const upload = multer({
  storage: multerStorage,
  fileFilter: multerFilter,
});
exports.uploadImages = upload.single('images');
//
exports.createClients = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.file) req.body.images = req.file.filename;
    const newClient = { ...req.body };
    await Client.create(req.body).then(
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        newClient,
      })
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

also with postman  sending request give  success response with no errors
i've tried location.replace() but also it didn't work for me
and is there another trick from server to get to the desired location out from client side

Comment: it is temporary solved by omitting res.status().json() to be res.redirect()  another impact was to remove multer from the middleware and make the request free of files

Answer (score 0):

`then` accepts a callback as a parameter.

```
then(() => location.assign('/[newUrl]'))
```

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work